# ListBox containing radio buttons - only the last one updates

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, radio-button

Alright, so I have a problem with the WPF radio button control which I am using in my project (WPF, C#, MVVM Light).

I have a ListBox, and each ListBoxItem has a template. Within each template is a group of Radio Buttons. The Radio Button's 'IsChecked' is linked to a property in the ListBoxItem data context.

That part looks like this:

```
<StackPanel Margin="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">
                            <RadioButton GroupName="VerbType" Content="Ichidan" IsChecked="{Binding VerbType, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=GenericRadioButtonConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}" />
                            <RadioButton GroupName="VerbType" Content="Godan" IsChecked="{Binding VerbType, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=GenericRadioButtonConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" />
                            <RadioButton GroupName="VerbType" Content="Irregular" IsChecked="{Binding VerbType, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=GenericRadioButtonConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}" />
                            <RadioButton GroupName="VerbType" Content="Suru" IsChecked="{Binding VerbType, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=GenericRadioButtonConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}" />
                        </StackPanel>
```

So the property is VerbType and it can be either 0,1,2 or 3 (int type).

The converter I use is as follows:

```
class GenericRadioButtonConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (parameter.ToString() == value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? parameter : System.Windows.Data.Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

So what exactly is going wrong? When you start the program it doesn't show the data from the underlying view model - all four radio buttons will be blank. This doesn't apply to the final ListBoxItem in the ListBox, which somehow works fine.

You might think that perhaps the data simply isn't set in the previous view models that are the data contexts for the other ListBoxItems. Well I thought about that, and I went back to the part of the program where it loads data from an XML file. I forced all of them to be '1'. It made no difference, except for the final item - in that case the radio button reflected the change. And it did run this part of the code for as many times as I expected it to.

It works for input : if I click on one of the radio buttons, it goes to the setter for the VerbType property and gives the correct one. And at that point, the one I click on will become selected.

It's just at the start. Why does only the final one load?

The final obvious question might be about differences for that final one. Is there something different in the data? Well to check this, I added an additional one to the data. As expected, it showed up as the new final item in the ListBox. Its initial radio button state was shown, but the previous final one was not.

Why this is the case I have no idea, but hopefully someone can share some wisdom on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer.

It seems that the key is in the GroupName property. As it stands in my question, I have four Radio Buttons, and five lots of those (four per ListBoxItem). Because they all have the same GroupName, it's treating them as one singular group of 20, rather than five groups of four.

The solution was to give the five groups different GroupNames. Now in my case the Radio Buttons were within a template, so I could't just change the GroupName to another String or else I'd just have the same problem again. So what I did was I bound the GroupName property to one of the properties of the data context of the ListBoxItem which I knew would be unique to each item in the list. Each ListBoxItem is something called a LanguageItem (i.e. that is the data context) and each LanguageItem has a unique ID. So I bound this ID property to the GroupName and it worked a charm.